# Ui Not updating (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have created a music player app, where when a user plays a song, a services is started and a notification with media control is displayed to the user.

I am facing issues when the user clicks on next or previous button in the notification panel.

When the user clicks on next button, the song changes and starts playing. 
The problem i am facing is that, when the song is changed, the Notification UI is updated with the new song information, but my App's player screen is  not updating the new song info.
I tried to debug, the data is proper, like the new song info which is being passed to TextView.setText() is correct, also when i immediately print TextView.getText() in the logs, its showing current info, but the UI is displaying old info and not reflecting this new info. The same is happening with other UI elements.

I am using a Manifest declared broadcast to receive Player control actions from the Notification.
When the broadcast receives the message to play next song, it calls the function to change the song, the song changes, the UI data is coming proper, the Textview is receiving it and getText() also returns the new  data but the UI is not updating.

Can anyone help me here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried doing adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()??? , maybe your view not updating new values of adapter

Comment: @Blu - Its not because of that, the TextView is not in the RecyclerView. But even when it was, it wouldn't update the View.